# Изменить автора фотографии

Tags: java, android

Можно ли на Android изменить автора фотографии? То есть, если открыть свойства файла фотографии на компьютере, то в строке "Авторы" был написан автор, например, имя пользователя аккаунта ВКонтакте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    File photo = new File("Путь_к_фото");
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photo.getCanonicalPath());
    exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ARTIST, "Test");
    exif.saveAttributes();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image]